# glDrawElementsInstanced: VertexAttribute mat4 not applied per instance

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, gldrawarrays

I have a problem with rendering multiple instances of an object, using one VertexArrayObject and four VertexBufferObjects.

I cannot get my head around what's wrong with my approach.
Here are the basics:

My relatively simple Vertex-Shader-code:

```
#version 330 core

precision highp float;

layout (location=0) in vec3 position;
layout (location=1) in vec2 texcoord;
layout (location=3) in mat4 modelViewMatrix;

out vec2 textureCoord;

uniform mat4 pr_matrix;

void main() {
    textureCoord = vec2(texcoord.x, texcoord.y);
    
    vec4 mvPos = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = pr_matrix * mvPos;
}
```

As you can see, I try to pass the model view matrix (model and camera_view combined) as an VertexAttribute.

As far as I know, a VertexAttribute is limited to a max of *vec4*, which means my *mat4* will actually take up *4 * vec4* locations.

Each VAO and VBO exists only once. I do not use a separate one for each *"gameobject"*, as some online-tutorials do.
Therefore I update each of the Buffers at specific positions. Buf first, let me show you the following code, which initializes them:

```
// VAO

this.vao = glGenVertexArrays();
glBindVertexArray(this.vao);


// buffer for vertex positions

this.positionVBO = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionVBO);

//  upload null data to allocate vbo storage in memory
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexpoints * Float.BYTES, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


// buffer for texture coordinates

this.textureVBO = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.textureVBO);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texturepoints * Float.BYTES, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


// buffer for transform matrices

this.matricesVBO = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.matricesVBO);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mtrxsize * Float.BYTES, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

// Byte size of one vec4
int vec4Size = 4 * Float.BYTES;

glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * vec4Size, 0);
glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * vec4Size, 1 * vec4Size);
glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * vec4Size, 2 * vec4Size);
glVertexAttribDivisor(5, 1);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(6);
glVertexAttribPointer(6, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * vec4Size, 3 * vec4Size);
glVertexAttribDivisor(6, 1);


//buffer for indices

this.indicesVBO = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indicesVBO);

glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indsize * Integer.BYTES, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);


//unbind buffers and array

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

As far as I'm aware, this initialization *should* correspond to the 4 VertexAttributes, defined in the Vertex-Shader.

For test purposes, I initialize 4 *gameobjects* (A1, A2, B1, B2), each with:

- 4 x vec3 points for the position-attribute, resulting in 4 * 3 = 12 floating-points pushed to the positionVBO
- 4 x vec2 points for the texture-attribute, resulting in 4 * 2 = 8 floating-points pushed to the textureVBO
- 6 x int points for the indices to draw (0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0), pushed to the indicesVBO
- 1 x mat4 for the modelViewMatrix-attribute, resulting in 4 * vec4 = 4 * 4 = 16 floating-points pushed to the matricesVBO

for each *gameobject* I push its data to the VBOs, using the following logic:

```
long vertoff = gameObjectVertOffset;   // offset of the current gameobject's vertex points in position data
long texoff = gameObjectTexOffset;     // offset of the current gameobject's texture points in texture data
long indoff = gameObjectIndOffset;     // offset of the current gameobject's indices in index data
long instoff = gameObjectMatrixOffset; // offset of the current gameobject's matrix (vec4) in matrices data

// upload new position data
if(gameObjectVertBuf.capacity() > 0) {
     gameObjectVertBuf.flip();
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionVBO);
     glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertoff * Float.BYTES, gameObjectVertBuf);
}

// upload new texture data
if(gameObjectTexBuf.capacity() > 0) {
     gameObjectTexBuf.flip();
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.textureVBO);
     glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texoff * Float.BYTES, gameObjectTexBuf);
}

// upload new indices data
if(gameObjectIndBuf.capacity() > 0) {
     gameObjectIndBuf.flip();
     glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indicesVBO);
     glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indoff * Integer.BYTES, gameObjectIndBuf);
}

// upload new model matrix data
if(gameObjectMatrixBuf.capacity() > 0) {
     gameObjectMatrixBuf.flip();
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.matricesVBO);
     glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instoff * Float.BYTES, gameObjectMatrixBuf);
}
```

Now to the actual rendering:

I want to draw element *A* 2 times and after that, element *B* 2 times.
for the instanced rendering, I group together the *gameobjects*, I knew i could render in one call, inside lists.

I now have two lists, each with two elements in them:

- List1[A1, A2]
- List2[B1, B2]

**Once** per list I now do:

```
  numInstances = 2;

  this.vao.bind();

  shaderprogram.useProgram();

  glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (int) (offset * Integer.BYTES), numInstances);

  offset += 6 * numInstances; // 6 indices * 2 instances
```

**The Problem:**

This results in the first two elements being rendered correctly, but the second two (from the second list / *glDrawElementsInstanced()* call) are rendered with the transformation matrices of the first two elements.

It does not matter, which list of objects are rendered first. The second iteration always seems to use the modelViewMatrix attributes from the first ones.

As far as I understood, the *glVertexAttribDivisor()* call should limit the iteration of the matrices per *instance* instead of per *vertex*.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the second two (from the second list / glDrawElementsInstanced() call) are rendered with the transformation matrices of the first two elements.

That's what you asked to do. How would the system know that it would need to use the *second* two elements from the array instead of the first two? All it sees is another draw call, and there are no changes to VAO state between them.

The system doesn't keep up with how many instances have been used in prior draw calls. That's your job.

Now, you could change the buffer binding for the attributes in question, but it's easier to use [base-instance rendering](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing). In these drawing functions, you specify an offset that is applied to the instance index for instanced attributes. So if you want to render two instances starting at instance index 2, you do this:

```
glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (int) (offset * Integer.BYTES), 2, 2);
```

Base instanced rendering is a GL 4.2 feature.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! @nicol-bolas
I thought that the 4th element I pass to glDrawElementInstanced() determines the offset? 
As you can see above, I pass (int) (offset * Integer.BYTES) and increment offset by 6 (indices) * 2 (number of instances I just drew).
So for the next call it would be 12 * Integer.BYTES. Is that not enough in this case?

Comment: @sgraut: That's the offset into the *index array*, not the offset into the instance arrays.

Comment: Yes, but isn't that correct? glDrawElementsInstanced() takes the offset into the index array  to look up, which (in my case 6) indices to render.
These 6 indices correspond to points in the positionVBO and points in the textureVBO, both of which seems to work correctly.
What is the difference to the matricesVBO? Especially since I use stride and glVertexAttribDivisor().

Comment: @sgraut: They're instanced arrays; that's *why* use used a divisor on them. Instance arrays *don't use* vertex indices; that's what makes them instanced arrays. Instance indices don't come from vertex indices.